# Mongo query with projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In mongo how to return all the match dict element from a list if the condition is match.

here is my data:

```
    {"packages": [
       {"package_name" : "abc", "installed_date" : "2016-08-03"},
       {"package_name" : "def", "installed_date" : "2016-08-04"},
       {"package_name" : "ghi", "installed_date" : "2016-08-03"},
       ]
    }
```

How should I query to get all the dictionary which match `{"installed_date" : "2016-08-03"}`

I tried:

`db.resource.find({packages: {"$elemMatch": {installed_date: "2016-08-03"}}})`

But this give me all the array element. I would like to get the dict element which match `{installed_date: "2016-08-03"}`

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you add a blank object as the first argument: db.resource.find({}, {packages: {"$elemMatch": {installed_date: "2016-08-03"}}})

Comment: Doesn't looks to be working, It returns all the other packages which doesn't ve that date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try mongo aggregation:

```
db.resource.aggregate([
  {'$match':{'packages.installed_date':'2016-08-03'}}, 
  {'$unwind':'$packages'}, 
  {'$match':{'packages.installed_date':'2016-08-03'}}, 
  {'$group':{'_id':'$_id', 'packages':{'$push':'$packages'}}}
])
```

Answer (score 3):

For a solution that does not use the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator, consider using **[`$map`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** alongside **[`$setDifference`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/)**, where you can "filter" array contents.

This is more efficient since it runs within a single **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline and also **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** produces a cartesian product of the documents i.e. a copy of each document per array entry, which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore takes time to produce as well processing the documents during the flattening process:

```
db.resource.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "packages": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$packages",
                            "as": "item",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$item.installed_date", "2016-08-03" ] },
                                    "$$item",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

In the above pipeline, the **[`$map`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array.

The **[`$setDifference`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final `packages` array that has elements with `installed_date = "2016-08-03"`.

Answer (score 1):

try below query: it will work for mongodb 3.2

```
db.resource.aggregate([
    {$match:{"packages.installed_date" : "2016-08-03"}},
    { $project: {
        package: {$filter: {
            input: '$packages',
            as: 'package',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$package.installed_date', "2016-08-03"]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

this will work without multiple match condition and $unwind

Comment: Thanks I will try when i upgrade it to 3.2

Comment: great , If it's possible then upgrade to 3.2. there is lots of new things and better performance. see http://www.slideshare.net/chenghanTsai1/mongodb-300-vs-26x-vs-24x-benchmark